# an error was encountered while retrieving the user profile

Tags: sharepoint, user-profile

I am getting this error while trying to retrieve a user profile:

```
An error was encountered while retrieving the user profile.
```

here is my code:

```cs
foreach (SPUser parent in parentGroup.Users)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
        {
            using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = site.OpenWeb(web.ID))
            {
                elevatedWeb.EnsureUser(parent.LoginName);
            }
        }
    });
    web.EnsureUser(parent.LoginName);
    try
    {
        UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(parent.LoginName);
        if ((bool)profile["ParentAssignmentSubscribe"].Value)
        {
            receivingParents.Add(new SlkUser(parent));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("failed to load profile of " + parent.LoginName + " in order to send them an assignment notification for web " + web.Name + ". The error returned was: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

obviously the user does exist, because i am getting his username from the group, and i also am using EnsureUser. what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is because your process cannt found your user profile .

Can you try the below steps ?

1. Open Central Administrator-→Security-→General Security，copy user name from Configure  service accounts
2. Open Central Administrator-→Application Management →Service Application→Manage Service Applications.
3. Click User Profile Service from the page you have opened at step2 , and select Manage User Profile from People
4. You can search the user profile by user name which you have copied at step1 ,  If you cant find it , that might be your error reason.
5. Click New Profile，create a new profile for your user name(at step1).

Comment: hmm.... i dont know how i missed this. i swear his profile existed before though... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
user = profileManager.GetUserProfile(_userName)
```

Should instead be:

```
user = profileManager.GetUserProfile(@"domain name\username");
```